# Python: attribute is not able to append

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem where when I use the (def checkIn) function, it shows 'str' object has no attribute 'append'. I have created a list for petName = [] but it doesn't seem to be able to append input.

```
staffID = 'admin'
password = 'admin'
petType = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Rodent']
petName = []

def loginFunction(s, p):
    # Login inputs
    staffID = input("Enter Staff ID: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    loginTrust = False
    while (loginTrust is False):
        if (staffID == 'admin') and (password == 'admin'):
            print("Successfully logged in")
            loginTrust = True

        else:
            print("Wrong ID or Password. Please enter again. ")
            loginTrust = False
            staffID = input("Enter Staff ID: ")
            password = input("Password: ")
```

## ISSUE

```
def checkIn(petType, petName):
    petName = str(input("Enter pet name: "))
    petName.append(petName)
    tempList.append(petName)
    boardedPets.extend(tempList)

def FrontDeskMenu():
    print("\nTaylor's Pet Hotel\nFront Desk Admin")
    print("A. Check in pets")
    print("B. Check out pets")
    print("C. Payment")
    print("D. Rooms Availability")
    print("E. History")
    print("F. Exit\n")

    userInput = input("What would you like to do today?: ")

    inputCheck = False
    while (inputCheck is False):
        if (userInput.lower() == 'a'):
            checkIn(petType, petName)
            inputCheck = True
        elif (userInput.lower() == 'f'):
            quit()
        else: 
            print("Invalid value! Please try again.")
            userInput = input("What would you like to do today?: ")
            inputCheck = False


loginFunction(staffID, password)
FrontDeskMenu()
```

Comment: You are overwritting your `petName` attribute with your `str(input())` call. Use a different variable name.

Comment: You are defining petname as an string , and then trying to append it to itself , try changing the names of the list and the input , the append function is a member of list not string

Comment: Please do NOT remove your code from the question, else the question, comments and answers make no sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First Of all, you did not initialize **petName = []** **tempList = []** **boardedPets = []** and you are overwritting your **petName**.

**The code Look Like and It will work I hope**

```
staffID = 'admin'
password = 'admin'
petType = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Rodent']
petName = []
tempList = []
boardedPets = []

def loginFunction(s, p):
    # Login inputs
    staffID = input("Enter Staff ID: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    loginTrust = False
    while (loginTrust is False):
        if (staffID == 'admin') and (password == 'admin'):
            print("Successfully logged in")
            loginTrust = True

        else:
            print("Wrong ID or Password. Please enter again. ")
            loginTrust = False
            staffID = input("Enter Staff ID: ")
            password = input("Password: ")

def checkIn(petType, petName):
    petName1 = str(input("Enter pet name: "))
    petName.append(petName1)
    tempList.append(petName1)
    boardedPets.extend(tempList)

def FrontDeskMenu():
    print("\nTaylor's Pet Hotel\nFront Desk Admin")
    print("A. Check in pets")
    print("B. Check out pets")
    print("C. Payment")
    print("D. Rooms Availability")
    print("E. History")
    print("F. Exit\n")

    userInput = input("What would you like to do today?: ")

    inputCheck = False
    while (inputCheck is False):
        if (userInput.lower() == 'a'):
            checkIn(petType, petName)
            inputCheck = True
        elif (userInput.lower() == 'f'):
            quit()
        else: 
            print("Invalid value! Please try again.")
            userInput = input("What would you like to do today?: ")
            inputCheck = False


loginFunction(staffID, password)
FrontDeskMenu()
```

[image: Code Output]

Answer (score 0):

You've  declared a string and trying 'append()' with string , it is a method , can use with list[] . use different name for string like pet_name , pet_name1 , petName . and also you should declare yor both lists - tempList and boardedpets .

```
tempList = []
boardedPets = []
```

then do this
    def checkIn(petType, petName):

```
 # pet_name= str(input("Enter pet name: ")) - no need to convert into string , input method gives always string so do not convert it
pet_name = input("Enter pet name: ")
petName.append(pet_name)
tempList.append(petName)
boardedPets.extend(tempList)
```